# Check if new starttime and endtime overlaps with starttime and endtime records in db using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I went through few answers and few match the solution I already have.

In my job scheduling app I want to check if a new added task overlaps with a task that is already in the db. The solution below gives me results for the basic scenarios but does not quite work for few. Like in case where endtime for a new task is the same as starttime of another.

e.g:

```
//this returns false as it should - no overlaps
New Task      : 14:00 - 15:00
Existing Task : 16:00 - 17:00

//this returns true, as existing taskstart is < new takend - 17:00 overlap
New Task      : 14:00 - 17:00
Existing Task : 16:00 - 17:00

//this scenario should return false
/*udpated*/the tasks do not overlap here but touch each other
New Task      : 14:00 - 16:00
Existing Task : 16:00 - 17:00

private bool CheckForOtherTasks(int UserId, DateTime _dtTaskStart, DateTime _dtTaskEnd)
{
    bool _bTasksExist = false;
    using (var _dbContext = new task_Entities())
    {
        _bTasksExist = (from t in _dbContext.Tasks
                        where t.UserId == UserId
                        where t.dtTaskStart < _dtTaskEnd && _dtTaskStart < t.dtTaskEnd
                        select t).Any();
    }

    return _bTasksExist;
}
```

The above solution works fine until there new endtime == existing starttime or vice versa.

This solution seems to solve it but I am unsure how to implement it along with LINQ without iterating through all the records. [How check intersection of DateTime periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325124/how-check-intersection-of-datetime-periods)

Would using LINQ for this task be a good approach or using a Stored Procedure to returns results be a better option?

Also, would a library such as https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET be ideal for a small project.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `... where t.dtTaskStart <= _dtTaskEnd && _dtTaskStart <= t.dtTaskEnd ...` ?

Comment: Well, that would return me the result as true, which means it is overlapping. I think i should rephrase my question. I want the method to return false in the condition when 16:00 == 16:00 or 16:00 < 16:00

Comment: `//this scenario should return false` Isn't that what your code already does?

Comment: Apparently it wasn't and hence I posted the question. Now that I debug again it is returning false.

Comment: Dont change the title if you have resolved the issue or not. [Mark the answer that helped you to mark it as resolved.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) If no answer provided the solution, add your own.

Answer (score 0):

> The above solution works fine until there new endtime == existing starttime or vice versa.

Then simply change the conditions from `<` to `<=` and from `>` to `>=`:

```
    _bTasksExist = (from t in _dbContext.Tasks
                    where t.UserId == UserId
                    where t.dtTaskStart <= _dtTaskEnd && _dtTaskStart <= t.dtTaskEnd
                    select t).Any();
```

Comment: I actually want to return false went 16:00 == 16:00 as when this happens the time do not overlap but as touching each other. I should be able to add a task that are next to each other. Say 15:00 - 16:00 , 16:00 - 17:00

Comment: So your initial condition seems to be correct. Does your original code returns true with times like this?

Comment: It was returning true and hence it stumped me, but now that I debug it again, it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the above test scenario, Initially the returned value was "True". After posting the question, I took a break and got back to start again and it gave me the results as expected.

It's 1:30 AM here is NZ and what I require before writing any more code is some sleep. The test that returned "False" had the endtime "17:00" which was from a previous debug session and the breakpoint was never cleared.

So the answer to my question is. Rest and then Test.